# How to determine the equation and length of this curve consistently formed by the intersection of Circles

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

Consider a Point $A$ that moves linearly on the positive $x$-axis with the velocity $1$ m/s and another Point $B$ at a distance $L$ from $A$ with position $(L,0)$. With each forward motion of point $A$ the Point $B$ moves in an arc upward (i.e. along positive $y$-axis) consistently maintaining the distance $L$ from point $A$. As soon as Point $A$ reaches $x=L$, the Point $B$ is perpendicular to Point $A$ and its position is $(L,L)$.

How do you then determine the equation and length of the path that $B$ traces during the period $A$ traverses from $x=0$ to $L$?

Comment: It seems to me from your description that $B$ has always a $x$ coordinate of $L$. Thus $B$ follows the segment $(L,0)$ to $(L,L)$... If you are looking for something else, can you clarify?

Comment: Actually B is having a constant distance L always with respect to the position of A. To achieve this B is moving in an arc until it reaches it final position (L,L) and at that moment A is at (0,L)

Comment: @KenW At that moment a reaches x=L i.e. a is at (L,0)

Comment: "As soon as Point A reaches x=L, the Point B is perpendicular to Point A..." - This makes absolutely no sense.  It seems to me that you want to specify that B moves in a direction perpendicular to A, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: No, B doesn't moves in a direction perpendicular to A. It is at the position which is perpendicular to A only when A has reached x=L, until then it always moves in an arc maintaining the constant distance L and reaches (L,L) when A is at (0,L).

Comment: You are still making no sense.  How can a position be perpendicular to another position?

Comment: In the partial answer below, I listed (1) and (2) as the constraints that A and B should satisfy.

Comment: @RonGordon Isn't a segment from (L,0) perpendicular to (L,L)... ALso in my previous comment I made a mistake regarding position of A it should be A is at (L,0)

Comment: A segment from $(0,0)$ to $(L,0)$ is perpendicular to a segment from $(L,0)$ to $(L,L)$.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @mike The constraints are true. But what methods  can we apply to solve it?

Comment: @RonGordon Yes...

Comment: You may solve $y_B(t)$ in terms of $x_B(t),t$ from (1) and substitute its differentiation into (2) and obtain an ODE for $x_B(t)$.  You may then solve this ODE...

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Comment: @mike I am not able to obtain the ODE itself and I was looking for a way to obtain a solution using geometry...

Comment: I was told about this problem by a colleague..

Comment: @RonGordon Please read the edited version of this problem and help me out...

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ and $v$ be the speeds of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Then, if $A\equiv(ut,0)$ and $B\equiv(x,y)$, you have $$\begin {cases} (x-ut)^2+y^2=L^2 \\ \\ \dot x^2 + \dot y^2=v^2 \end {cases}$$Factor $\dot y^2$ in the first side of the second equation to get $$\dot y=\frac v {\sqrt {\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2+1}}$$ Differentiate the first equation with respect to $\,t$ and divide by $\,\dot y$.

You obtain $$\sqrt{L^2-y^2}\left(\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac uv \sqrt {\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2+1}\right)+y=0$$ Note that the result depends only on the ratio $\frac uv$ .

After some manipulations you get a quadratic equation in $\frac{dx}{dy}$ with coefficients in $y\,$.

Let $f(y)$ be the right solution $\,$(squaring can introduce extraneous solutions).

Then solve $$\int_0^L f(y)\;dy=0$$ as an equation in $\frac uv$ .

At the end plot $$x(y)=L+\int_0^y f(z)\;dz$$ on $[0,L]$ with that value of the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinity of solutions if there is no special constraint (such as the $x$ coordinate of $B$ is fixed).

If you fix $x_B=L$, then $y_B=x_A$...

EDIT: another interesting case is if $B$ is on a circle of center $(L,\dfrac{L}{2})$ and of radius $\dfrac{L}{2}$. Then of course you know the equation of the curve, but you might want to compute the coordinates of $B$ as a function of $x_A$.

EDIT2 (in response to the fact that this curve is impossible).

$B$ is on the circle, thus $(x_B-L)^2+(y_B-\dfrac{L}{2})^2=\dfrac{L}{2}^2$

And $AB=L$, thus $(x_B-x_A)^2+y_B^2=L^2$

From the two equation you have the following equation in $x_B$:

$(x_B-L)^2+(\sqrt{L^2-(x_B-x_A)^2}-\dfrac{L}{2})^2=\dfrac{L}{2}^2$

Comment: In such a scenario the distance between A and B would fail to be a constant L during the path where A moves from 0 to L.

Comment: @KenW Absolutely not. The speed with which the point B will travel its curve will not be continuous, but of course it is possible.

Comment: In reply to: "EDIT: another interesting case is if B is on a circle of center (L,L2) and of radius L2. Then of course you know the equation of the curve, but you might want to compute the coordinates of B as a function of xA."Yes, but we don't know certainly B would not be at that position as it is traveling in an arc and its x-coordinate is NOT fixed.

Comment: @KenW This is why I have made my very first comment: there is an infinity of such curves possible. $B$ can travel many paths while always following $AB=L$.

Comment: This curve is absolutely possible and the main idea is that B is moving consistently in an arc maintaining the fixed distance L until it reaches the point (L,L) and exactly perpendicular to A. Hence B will never acquire the position of the centre of circle (L,L/2) since it contradicts the requirements it takes to complete its path.

Comment: No, actually B can travel in only one way as it is required to reach (L,L) while moving in an arc...

Comment: @KenW $(L,\dfrac{L}{2})$ is the coordinate of the center of the circle, not a point by which $B$ goes through... By the way, my first answer ($B$ with a fixed $x_B$) is the only one that gives the additional constraint of the constant speed of $B$.

Comment: @KenW But what do you call an arc???

Comment: By arc, I am trying to mean it moves in a circle with radius L. And while it moves from certain point say l1 to l2, A has reached a point where the distance is again fixed.

Comment: Actually B will indeed be the at the point on the circle (L,L/2) but only when A has reached x=L.

Comment: @KenW I suggest you write more clearly your problem. Reading your last comment, I understand suddenly that $B$ is on a circle of radius $L$...!! And that the distance $AB$ is not constant (comment: where the distance is again fixed)!!! I doubt this is what you mean. If $A$ is moving, $B$ is not on a circle of radius $L$ with center $A$, since $A$ is moving... And if you have no constraint on the speed of $B$, you have an infinity of such curves. By the way, if $B$ is on (L,L/2) when $A$ is on (L,0), then the distance is L/2...

Comment: Well, it seems there is a lot of confusion with this. First of all I meant a position on the circle i.e. (L,L) and NOT center of the circle which is (L,L/2). Secondly, the path traced by B is NOT circular rather it is a curve which is formed by the intersection of circles that are formed taking the variable position of A as center... This problem requires a lot of  co-ordinate geometry and the solution of its arc-length IMO is that of an elliptic integral. I suggest you to focus on the problem more clearly as there is only one solution possible not infinite.

Comment: @KenW I think you need to consider that there is no "intersection of circles" of a center $A$ which is a moving target. If you take my first (the simplest) answer, that is $y_B=x_A$ (with $x_B=L$), you will note that at all times the distance $AB=L$, at all times! This means that if you stop the "movement" of $A$, at each time you do this, you will notive that$B$ is on a circle of center $A$ and of radius $L$... But this is only one solution (the simplest) and if you think your problem is more complex, be my guest!

Comment: Well you answers and help were helpful. But the problem is more complex and it was my own interpretation that the curve traced by B is formed by the intersection of circles. The most important thing in this problem is that B is not moving in a straight line it is always moving in an arc (i.e. its path is tracing over some angle)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution yet.

Let $v_A=1m/s,x_A(t)=v_A t,y_A(t)=0$.

$$(y_B(t)-y_A(t))^2+(x_B(t)-x_A(t))^2=L^2\tag{1}$$

$$\left(\frac{d x_B(t)}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d y_B(t)}{dt}\right)^2=v_B^2=1\tag{2}$$

$$x_B(0)=L,y_B(0)=0\tag{3}$$

$$x_B(T)=L,y_B(T)=L\tag{4}$$

These are the two equations and boundary conditions that the coordinates of point B should satisfy.

EDIT:
From (1) we get:
$$x_B(t)=t+\sqrt{L^2-y_B^2(t)}\tag{5}$$
Notice that this solution satisfies the initial condition (3).

From (5) we obtain:
$$\frac{d x_B(t)}{dt}=1-\frac{y_B(t)}{(L^2-y_B^2(t))^{1/2}}\frac{d y_B(t)}{dt}\tag{6}$$

Substitution of (6) into (2) leads to an ODE for $y_B(t)$:

$$\left(\frac{d y_B(t)}{dt}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{y_B(t)}{(L^2-y_B^2(t))^{1/2}}\frac{d y_B(t)}{dt}\right)^2=0\tag{7}$$

We can now solve $\frac{d y_B(t)}{dt}$ from (7) and obtain:

$$\frac{d y_B(t)}{dt}=\frac{2y_B(t)(L^2-y_B^2(t))^{1/2}}{L^2}\tag{8}$$

The solution of $y_B(t)$ is given by:

$$y_B(t)=\frac{4L\exp\left(\frac{2t}{L}+L C_1\right)}{1+4\exp\left(\frac{4t}{L}+2L C_1\right)}\tag{9}$$

Setting $y_B(T)=L$, we can determine the integration constant $C_1$ in (9) so (9) becomes
$$y_B(t)=\frac{2L\exp\left(\frac{2(t+T)}{L}\right)}{\exp\left(\frac{4t}{L}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{4T}{L}\right)}\tag{10}$$.

But I was not able to set $y_B(0)=L$ in (10) to determine $T$.

Comment: I am not able to obtain the ODE itself and I was looking for a way to obtain a solution using geometry which I think would be much more simplified..